# Pandas do roll up based on field

Tags: pandas

I am not sure what exactly to look for, but I want to do a roll up based on a field, so if I have this data as input:

```
------------------
buyer   sum of bid 
------------------
buyer1  350 
buyer1  283 
buyer2  236         
buyer2  80 
buyer3  76 
buyer4  69
```

I want to roll up while still maintain the original data. I would like to sort by "sum per buyer" but still keep the buyer grouping. The output would be:

```
-----------------------------------
buyer   sum of bid    sum per buyer
-----------------------------------
buyer1  350           633
buyer1  283 
buyer2  236           316       
buyer2  80 
buyer3  76            76
buyer4  69            69
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
df['sum per buyer'] = df['buyer'].map(df.groupby('buyer')['sum of bid'].sum())
df
    buyer  sum of bid  sum per buyer
0  buyer1         350            633
1  buyer1         283            633
2  buyer2         236            316
3  buyer2          80            316
4  buyer3          76             76
5  buyer4          69             69
```